# Recursive select or join on single table

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a table which has a column for **name**, **grp_ip** *(group id)* and **pgrp_id** *(parent group id)*.

My starting point is to select any entry that has a parent group id of 1083:

```
select grp_id, pgrp_id, name from CM_GROUP where pgrp_id = 1083
```

which shows me the following

| grp_id | pgrp_id | name |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1084 | 1083 | ACT |
| 1085 | 1083 | NSW |
| 1086 | 1083 | VIC |
| 1087 | 1083 | QLD |
| 1088 | 1083 | SA |
| 1089 | 1083 | WA |
| 1090 | 1083 | TAS |
| 1091 | 1083 | NT |

The next query is to select any entry under the first (1084) entry:

```
select grp_id, pgrp_id, name from CM_GROUP where pgrp_id = 1084
```

| grp_id | pgrp_id | name |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1095 | 1084 | Canberra |
| 1849 | 1084 | Bega |
| 1850 | 1084 | Wagga Wagga |

Then another level:

```
select grp_id, pgrp_id, name from CM_GROUP where pgrp_id = 1095
```

| grp_id | pgrp_id | name |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1098 | 1095 | System 1 |
| 1099 | 1095 | System 2 |
| 1101 | 1095 | System 3 |
| 1102 | 1095 | System 4 |
| 1103 | 1095 | System 5 |
| 1104 | 1095 | System 6 |
| 1105 | 1095 | System 7 |
| 1106 | 1095 | System 8 |
| 1112 | 1095 | System 9 |
| 1207 | 1095 | System 10 |
| 1208 | 1095 | System 11 |
| 1423 | 1095 | System 12 |
| 1424 | 1095 | System 13 |
| 1669 | 1095 | System 14 |
| 1672 | 1095 | System 15 |
| 1834 | 1095 | System 16 |
| 1846 | 1095 | System 17 |

Ultimately I'm after a response that combines these three levels that looks similar to this:

| system id | system name | site id | site name | state id | state name |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1098 | System 1 | 1095 | Canberra | 1084 | ACT |
| 1099 | System 2 | 1095 | Canberra | 1084 | ACT |
| 1101 | System 3 | 1095 | Canberra | 1084 | ACT |
| 1102 | System 4 | 1095 | Canberra | 1084 | ACT |
| 1103 | System 5 | 1095 | Canberra | 1084 | ACT |
| 1104 | System 6 | 1095 | Canberra | 1084 | ACT |
| 1105 | System 7 | 1095 | Canberra | 1084 | ACT |
| 1106 | System 8 | 1095 | Canberra | 1084 | ACT |
| 1112 | System 9 | 1095 | Canberra | 1084 | ACT |
| 1207 | System 10 | 1095 | Canberra | 1084 | ACT |
| 1208 | System 11 | 1095 | Canberra | 1084 | ACT |
| 1423 | System 12 | 1095 | Canberra | 1084 | ACT |
| 1424 | System 13 | 1095 | Canberra | 1084 | ACT |
| 1669 | System 14 | 1095 | Canberra | 1084 | ACT |
| 1672 | System 15 | 1095 | Canberra | 1084 | ACT |
| 1834 | System 16 | 1095 | Canberra | 1084 | ACT |
| 1846 | System 17 | 1095 | Canberra | 1084 | ACT |
| 1852 | System 1 | 1849 | Bega | 1084 | ACT |
| 1854 | System 2 | 1849 | Bega | 1084 | ACT |
| 1857 | System 3 | 1849 | Bega | 1084 | ACT |
| 1928 | System 4 | 1849 | Bega | 1084 | ACT |
| 1127 | System 1 | 1116 | Coffs Harbour | 1084 | NSW |
| 1129 | System 1 | 1117 | Dubbo | 1084 | NSW |
| 1327 | System 1 | 1307 | Melbourne | 1086 | VIC |
| 1852 | System 1 | 1849 | Hobart | 1084 | TAS |

...but continues to go through each of the other entries under 1083 and further down. I'm fairly new to sql and have tried searching for "sql for loops" and "sql for each" but I'm not hitting any gold.

I feel that if I could get on the right track or find the correct terminology, I could get a bit further.

Any advice or info would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: Please tag your question with the DBMS you are using.

Comment: You can find any type of recursive in this link https://github.com/AmirNBA9/SQLAssistant/tree/master/RecursiveCTE

Comment: As your own title says: write a **recursive** query :-) You probably find this in your docs under "recursive query", "recursve CTE" or "recursive WITH clause".

Comment: You want to find all 1084 children and their children and their children ... As you have only shown children and no grandchildren in your example, this leaves one question open: For the parent name you always want the 1084 name or the name of the direct parent (e.g. Canberra for 1095's children)?

Comment: HI @ThorstenKettner, I've added a few more examples into the proposed final result. Yes - ultimately the children of 1083, grandchildren and great grandchildren...

Comment: Oh, so it's always three levels; state, site, and system? Why then a recursive table? This makes querying the data an awful task. It would be much easier with three separate tables. Anyway, if this is three levels, you can *treat* your table as three separate tables with self joins (`select * from mytable states join mytable sites on sites.pgrp_id = states.grp_id ...`.

Answer (score 1):

It seems this is three levels: states, sites and systems. I wonder why this is a hierarchical table then, instead of just three separate ones. Your database allows  a country to be part of a country and a site part of a system, because the DBMS cannot see which is which.

I'd change the data model. But well, we *can* treat the one table like separate tables in our queries.

```
with states as
(
  select grp_id as state_id, name as state_name
  from mytable
  where pgrp_id = 1083
)
, sites as
(
(
  select grp_id as site_id, pgrp_id as state_id, name as site_name
  from mytable
  where pgrp_id in (select state_id from states)
)
, systems as
(
(
  select grp_id as system_id, pgrp_id as site_id, name as system_name
  from mytable
  where pgrp_id in (select site_id from sites)
)
select
  sy.system_id, sy.system_name, si.site_id, si.site_name, st.state_id, st.state_name
from states st
join sites si on si.state_id = st.state_id
join systems sy on sy.site_id = si.site_id
order by st.state_id, si.site_id, sy.system_id;
```

The same thing a lot shorter and a tad more prone to errors and maybe slightly less readable, because the IDs get their names in the very end:

```
select
  sy.prg_id as system_id, sy.name as system_name,
  si.prg_id as site_id, si.name as site_name,
  st.prg_id as state_id, st.name as state_name
from mytable st
join mytable si on si.pgrp_id = st.prg_id
join mytable sy on sy.pgrp_id = si.prg_id
where st.pgrp_id = 1083
order by st.prg_id, si.prg_id, sy.prg_id;
```